# PUT with optional parameters

Tags: web-services, rest, http, put

I must fulfill a web service with `PUT` as method to send changes. This service is used to change configurations. So, for example, if I send `{"varA":true}` to `url/configurationchage`it sets the corresponding variable, and if I send `{"varB":true}` it changes `varB` without affecting `varA`.

I always though that `PUT` (and searching google it seems as if I am right) just overwrites the resource (or creates it if not existing). Which I think would mean that I always have to send all variables, or the ones that are not sent will be deleted. So, is the behavior of this web service correct??

**WITH EXAMPLES**

```
PUT {"varA":true}
Resource content: {"varA": true}

PUT {varB:true}
```

- **happening:** `Resource content: {"varA": true, "varB":true}`
- **what I think should happen:** `Resource content: {"varB":true}`

Comment: You said it yourself "or creates it if **not existing**".  Basically your second call to set varB is finding the object that you set with your first PUT (which is varA), so that server object not contains both values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not. You probably want to look at the PATCH method instead (see http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc5789.html)